# Solr get count of aggregation function

Tags: solr, aggregate, facet

If a have Solr data for users and goals

```
{user_id: user1,goals: 1}
{user_id: user1,goals: 3}
{user_id: user2,goals: 0}
{user_id: user2,goals: 4}
{user_id: user3,goals: 2}
{user_id: user3,goals: 1}
```

I'm wanting to find out how many users have scored 1,2,3... goals in total.

So for the data above I want a query that can return

```
{goals: 3, count: 1}
{goals: 4, count: 2}
```

So far I have a query that can return the total number of goals for each user but am not sure if it's possible to facet on the totals

My query so far

```
{
  "user_facet":
  {
    "type":"terms",
    "field":"user_id",
    "facet":
    {
      "sum_of_goals":"sum(goals)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you rephrase? the sample it's hard to understand, does not seem to match the data to me...

Comment: basically there are two stages, totalling the goals per user so user 1 = 4, user 2 = 4, user 3 = 3 goals. Then I want to count the number of users who have scored 3 goals = 1, 4 goals = 2

Comment: so what does {user_id: user1,goals: 1} mean, that user1 has completed "goal 1" of that "user1 has completed 1 goals in total"

Comment: it means user 1 has 1 goal in total for the period the record represents, e.g. in week 1 user 1 achieved 1 goal, in week 2 user 1 achieved 3 goals, in total user 1 achieved 4 goals and I want a query that can tell be how many users achieved each number of goals in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get this with json facets. But for sure it's possible with  [Streaming Expressions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions). They are a bit more complex to get started, but you can accomplish many more things.

Comment: Thank you, for now I'm using the query to get the totals for each user and processing the results in Ruby to calculate the data I need but I will look into streaming expressions